# APT: error: attribute android:usesPermissionFlags not found

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to compile simple app in Flutter. I am using `flutter_reactive_ble` library and I have following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/michalsniady/Desktop/Engineering Thesis/take_your_pills/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:18: AAPT: error: attribute android:usesPermissionFlags not found.
```

My permissions in main Android Manifest look like that:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission 
 android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" 
 android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

And my `build.gradle` code looks like that:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
}
```

Does anyone has any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 10):

Try to compile and/or target Android 31. The feature you're trying to use has been added to Android 31 (Platform 31 = Android 12).